# App Engine, Android Studio, Generate Endpoint "No JPA @Entity Class found in MessageData2.java"

Tags: google-app-engine, android-studio

this is a regression.  Earlier (than Jan 2014) versions of Android Studio would successfully generate the Endpoint code from a model.

steps: New Project, Tools > Generate App Engine, select any of the endpoint models (DeviceInfo or Message) or add a class file (with @Entity etc).  Tools> Generate Endpoint

gets: No JPA @Entity Class found in MessageData2.java  in dialog box Failed to Generate Endpoint Class

expected: code generation as in the past

update: rolled back to 0.4.2 (it used to work) and yikes! still getting Dialog Box (really stuck now).

update [not stuck anymore]: rolled back MAVEN to 3.0.5, built new clean project, app{appname}-endpoints succesfully built, then Generate Endpoint worked (still has the bug where client code is not copied to endpoint directory, look for it in {appname}-AppEngine/target and copy by hand to {appname}-endpoint tree

i logged a bug through App Studio to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65270  if you want to track

Comment: This is getting worse.  in Android Studio 0.4.4 (Feb 9 '14), generate endpoint is DOA.  Selecting the file to generate the endpoint from gives "Select a Module..." dialog box and fails.  Selecting the module gives "Select a java file..." and fails.  yikes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(answer from comment on https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65270 )

Tools>Generate Endpoints will work in 0.4.3 by adding this code to pom.xml

trevorjohns@google.com :"
I ran into this problem recently. Adding:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

to my backend pom.xml seemed to fix it."

yes, fixed!

Comment: this is no longer a functioning a workaround for 0.4.4 ... :(

Comment: 0.4.4 all Maven projects are gone.  No way to update App Engine.  if that's your flow stay away for now.

Comment: 0.5.1 for me, and still the same issues